# python: Unexpected version found while deserializing dlib::shape_predictor

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I'm trying to use python27 (IDLE) to get the facial landmarks from an image. When I run the code bellow I get the output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matth\Desktop\testmctest.py", line 11, in 
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)
RuntimeError: Unexpected version found while deserializing dlib::shape_predictor.

Using dlib version 19.10 (stored on my desktop)
Using the shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2 file from http://dlib.net/files/ (Stored on my c drive inside my python folder)

```
import numpy 
import cv2
import dlib

 PREDICTOR_PATH = "C:/Python27/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2"
 predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)
 cascade_path='haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
 cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)


def get_landmarks(im):
  rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(im, 1.3,5)
 x,y,w,h =rects[0]
 rect=dlib.rectangle(x,y,x+w,y+h)
return numpy.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(im, rect).parts()])

def annotate_landmarks(im, landmarks):
im = im.copy()
for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks):
    pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
    cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,
                fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,
                fontScale=0.4,
                color=(0, 0, 255))
    cv2.circle(im, pos, 3, color=(0, 255, 255))
return im

im=cv2.imread('face_leo1.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Result',annotate_landmarks(im,get_landmarks(im)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

The dlib and shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2 where out of 'sync'
fixed by using the from [The github page](https://github.com/AKSHAYUBHAT/TensorFace/blob/master/openface/models/dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat)

Comment: I'm having this issue now... can you tell me where can I find the new predictor? The link you posted doesn't exist.

Comment: This has helped me:
https://github.com/codeniko/shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, extract bz2 archive first and create dlib.shape_predictor with .dat file as input